# How to pipe command output to other commands?

Tags: bash, pipe

Example:

`ls | echo` prints nothing ( a blank line, actually ). I'd expect it to print a list of files.

`ls | grep 'foo'`, on the other hand, works as expected ( prints files with 'foo' in their name ).

What I do in these situations is something like:
     `ls | while read OUT; do echo $OUT; done` but this is rather cumbersome.

Why does piping work with some commands, but not with others ? How can I circumvent this issue ?

Comment: What do you expect `ls | echo` to do? why not simply run `ls`?

Comment: I used the simplest example that illustrates my point. I actually encountered this problem when I was trying to make a one-liner that would show git objects in the object store and their type. So, I piped object ID's to `git cat-file`, but it just didn't work. Apparently, echo has the same behaviour, so I used it as an example.

Comment: also look at the -n command for xargs, it says how many arguments to put on subcommand.  ` ... | xargs -n1 git cat-file`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503197/130767

Answer (score 170, accepted):

There is a distinction between command line arguments and standard input.  A pipe will connect standard output of one process to standard input of another.  So

```
ls | echo
```

Connects standard output of ls to standard input of echo.  Fine right?  Well, echo ignores standard input and will dump its command line arguments - which are none in this case to - to its own stdout. The output: nothing at all.

There are a few solutions in this case.  One is to use a command that reads stdin and dumps to stdout, such as cat.

```
ls | cat
```

Will 'work', depending on what your definition of work is.

But what about the general case. What you really want is to convert stdout of one command to command line args of another.  As others have said, `xargs` is the canonical helper tool in this case, reading the command line args for a command from its stdin and constructing commands to run.

```
ls | xargs echo
```

You could also use the substitution command `$()` to do what you want.

```
echo $(ls)
```

Both of these tools are pretty core to shell scripting, you should learn both.

For completeness, as you indicate in the question, the other base way to convert stdin to command line args is the shell's builtin `read` command. It converts "words" (words as defined by the `IFS` variable) to a temp variable, which you can use in any command runs.

Comment: A very helpful an informative answer, thank you ! I'm currently learning bash, and I've seen both xargs and the $(*) notation before, but didn't pay much attention to them. Now I know just how important they are, and will definitely look into them.

Comment: xargs may have been what OP was looking for.

Comment: So I remember: `xargs` is for those commands that only accept cmd parameters - `echo` here -, but no std input from commands before - `cat` can do.

Answer (score 24):

`ls | echo` prints just a blank line because `echo` reads no input; the last command of the pipeline is actually `echo` that prints nothing but a blank line.

Generally:

```
a | b
```

makes sure that the output of `a` become the input of `b`. I suggest you to read the `Pipelines` section of `man bash`.

---

If you really want to use `ls` and `echo` together here's some (pretty useless) examples:

```
ls | xargs -L 1 echo
echo `ls`
for i in `ls` ; do echo $i ; done
```

Comment: Examples may be pretty useless, but it helped me tremendously, in order to find a safe way to remove all folder matching a certain pattern, like so: `for i in \`find . -iname pattern\` ; do rm $i -rf ; done`

Answer (score 15):

If you want to `echo` the `ls` command try:

```
ls | xargs echo
```

This will call `echo` with the output of `ls`.

Comment: Or `ls | xargs -I {} echo {}` if you want it to be called for each line individually

Comment: @AlexAbdugafarov why do you say "line"? I think it is supposed to be "file/directory" instead. Also if there are spaces in either file or directory, this is not going to get you the correct output. It should be `ls | xargs -0 -I {} echo {}`

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply use:

```
echo `ls`
```

Or much safer:

```
echo "`ls -lrt`"
```

Comment: Or even just `echo *`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved in several ways, such as [pipe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) `|`, [STDERR](https://linux.die.net/man/3/stderr) `2>`, [xargs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html), or by using the [Command Substitution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03) `$()`.

Example of using `xargs`:

```
ls | xargs echo
```