# Bash and double echo

Tags: bash

I have the following code. In all cases I'm expecting to get `1 1`. Could someone explain why I do not get the expected output in the first case?

The question seems to be very simple and I think I'm missing something basic.

Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash

f(){
    echo $1
}
ff(){
    echo $1 $1
}

# expecting 1 1, but got empty      
f 1 | ff

# ok
X=$(f 1)
ff $X
```

Comment: [My answer](http://superuser.com/questions/189362/how-to-pipe-command-output-to-other-commands/189386#189386) to a related question. The "stdin vs. command line" split is the same, but you don't really use xargs in functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example that doesn't work, the pipe sends stdout of your first function `f` to the stdin of your second function `ff`. The function `ff` is not processing its stdin; it's processing arguments passed to it.

Here's a way to make the first line work:

```
ff `f 1`
```

The backquotes execute the `f 1` and the resulting value is passed as an argument to `ff`.

You may also use `read` if you want to read the input:

```
ff()
{
  while read in
  do
    echo $in $in
  done
}
```

Comment: Nice addition, Spack!

Comment: `$(...)` [should be preferred to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/shell-programming-whats-the-difference-between-command-and-command) `\`...\``