# Use grep to find files and pipe/open to open them

Tags: command-line, grep, pipe

How can I pipe files from grep to open all matching files?

I've tried `grep -li "type" * | open`, but that does not work.

Comment: Not quite the exact same what you're asking, but [a related question/answer](http://superuser.com/questions/189362/how-to-pipe-command-output-to-other-commands/189386#189386)

Comment: What do you mean by "open"?  Do you want to output their contents to the screen?  Open them all in `emacs` in sequence?  Open them all in `emacs` at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many ways to do this (using find/exec, xargs,...), one could be :

```
grep -li "type" * | while read file; do echo "processing $file"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IFS=$'\n'; for i in $(grep -rli "type" *); do open "$i"; done
```

The IFS is necessary, so that it won't split filenames containing whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Use while read line loop:

```
| while read line
```

If

```
$ grep -l something *.py
file1.py
file2.py
```

Then

```
$ grep -l something *.py | while read line ; do open "$line" ; done
```

Is equivalent to

```
$ open "file1.py"
$ open "file2.py"
```

Using quotes like `"$line"` instead of just `$line` allows for it to match filenames that contain spaces, otherwise filenames with spaces will cause errors.
Notice that `line` is just a commonly-used name for a variable in this usage. It could just as easily be

```
$ grep -l something *.py | while read potato ; do open "$potato" ; done
```