# Need to understand the concept of xargs and pipes

Tags: linux, pipe

I have been struggling with this issue for a while now and would really appreciate it if someone could clarify it for me . Suppose I am trying to pipe the two commands together. `readlink` and `cat`

```
readlink Command output
$ readlink -f SUService.log
/cygdrive/c/SUService.log
```

Now if I try something like this (it fails)

```
$ readlink -f SUService.log | cat
```

While something like this will work

```
$ readlink -f SUService.log | xargs cat
```

I wanted to know why that is ? I have read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66111/why-does-pipe-not-work-with-cat-and-locate) post here in which the OP had a similar question
and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46372/whats-the-difference-between-stdin-and-arguments-passed-to-command) post which attempts to explain difference between an argument and an input however i still couldnt wrap my head around the accepted answer(s). From what I understand is that `readlink` returns the result to stdout which is the terminal screen while `cat` wants an input as argument. This in return prompts me to ask how do I know if the output of a command (such as locate or readlink) can work as an argument or not for the next command ? I have been doing more reading and it turns out i would like to know when I should be using the xarg command ?

Comment: I don't have time for a lengthy answer, but `stdout` can act as an arugment if the shell supports [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

Comment: I wrote this on superuser, but this may help: [pipe output to other command](http://superuser.com/a/189386/8804)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your example is rather confused.

You don't normally send just any characters to cat.

You normally send a file to cat.

Nevertheless, when you do send  some characters to cat, it prints the characters.

```
$ echo abc12123 | cat
abc12123
```

Normally you send a filename to cat

```
$ cat abc12123
cat: abc12123: No such file or directory
```

So notice that cat itself, deals differently with funny characters piped to it, vs being passed them as a parameter.

```
$ cat b.b
textofb.b

$ echo b.b | cat
b.b

$ cat b.b
textofb.b
```

i'll use a simpler example than yours

```
$ echo b.b | xargs cat
textofb.b
```

see it prints the contents of b.b  because  `asdfasdfs | xargs cat`, will send the output of asdfasdfs as a parameter to cat.

So

```
echo b.b | xargs cat   
=  
cat b.b
```

Whereas  `echo b.b | cat`    is not the same as `cat b.b`

Comment: Is there a way for me to tell if a certain command will send the output as a parameter as well ?

Comment: @MistyD yeah, `echo asdfsd | command`, and `command asdfasdf`, and see what it does. That's easier than reading a long man page which is the other way. but you learn by both trying and reading.

Comment: As for when to use xargs, I suppose, if you have a command, and you can't pipe to it, and you want to send the output of a command to it, and it only takes a parameter, then you could use xargs. or I suppose, command substitution. Personally, I think I may have used xargs once in Windows cmd to allow me to send info from a command, to a batch file(script) I wrote. I couldn't pipe to my batch file but my batch file could take a parameter.  windows cmd shell doesn't have substitution so I think I got a copy of xargs and used that.

Comment: cmd has a usage of the 'for' command that can send the output of a command to another command, as a parameter, but the linux solution - xargs is neater looking, and you can get xargs for windows. so that was when I used xargs.

Comment: john gives a good example based on yours.. cat is perhaps unusual in that piping to it has a different effect to giving a parameter, so if you wanted to pipe to cat but have it have the effect of sending it as a parameter, then use xargs. e.g. you want to pipe a filename to cat, but have the contents of the file outputted.

Comment: @barlop On the other hand, if you think of stdin as just another file, then the `cat` behavior is consistent: it prints out stdin just as it would a file supplied as an argument.

Comment: @John1024 well, then you're piping/giving it the contents of the file vs giving it the filename, which isn't that consistent. But putting that aside.. if cat by the perspective you pur forth, is consistent,  then what would that say about echo? (I guess if using that perspective, one would have to say echo is inconsistent)

Comment: @barlop It seems to me that there are two categories of commands here.  In one category, `cat`, just like `sed` and `awk`, will accept input from stdin just as it would input from a file named on the command line.  In the other category, commands, such as `echo`, `date`, and `ls`, do not use stdin at all.

Comment: @John1024  ah for some reason I thought you could pipe to echo, my bad  And you make a great point re e.g. sed

Answer (score 6):

The following command does *not* fail.  It simply does something you didn't expect:

```
readlink -f SUService.log | cat
```

When `cat` is given stdin, it copies it to stdout.  It does not look for filenames in it.

Alternatively, this will read from the named file:

```
cat "$(readlink -f SUService.log)"
```

`xargs` will also put the name on the `cat` command line, yielding the same result:

```
readlink -f SUService.log | xargs cat
```

Comment: thanks for explaining that but what I am looking for is when would i need to use xarg command ?

Comment: Use `xargs` when you want to use stdin as the arguments on a command line.  `echo filename | xargs cat` is the same as `cat filename`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the manpages for cat and xargs to see what they do.

```
man cat

cat - concatenate files and print on the standard output
```

And:

```
man xargs

xargs - build and execute command lines from standard input
```

Here's a little demo

## Let's create a test file:

```
echo "a" > test
echo "b" >> test
echo "c" >> test
```

## cat

```
cat test
```

Reads the file and gives:

```
a
b
c
```

## echo | cat

```
echo test | cat
```

According to `man cat`, this does the same as:

```
echo test | cat -
```

Which pipes `test` into cat's stdin, and tells cat to read from stdin.

## echo | xargs cat

```
echo test | xargs cat
```

Generates and executes the following command:

```
cat test
```

The output of this we've already shown.

If we run

```
<test xargs -n1 cat
```

Xargs sees this on input:

```
a
b
c
```

And it generates the following commands:

```
cat a
cat b
cat c
```

Which should result in three errors since those files do not exist.

### Why the `-n1`?

According to `man xargs`, the `-n1` tells xargs to use one argument (read from stdin) in each command that it generates.

If we use `-n2` instead, we generate the following which uses up to two parameters per command:

```
cat a b
cat c
```

And if we use `-n3` or higher, or simply omit the `-n`:

```
< test xargs cat
```

We get:

```
cat a b c
```